# Read HDF5 in streaming in java

Tags: java, hdf5, hdf

I want to read some HDF5 stream of several gigabytes. I also want to stay in native java for portability.

I have tried Java HDF Object Package and Java HDF5 Interface (JHI5) but theses are some JNI solutions (that I might reconsider if i don't find better options).

https://github.com/jamesmudd/jhdf is a native java library but does not support slicing or streaming so is not usable for big files.

Is there some more option in native Java ?

Edit : I found this : https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf-java/current/
It's supports slicing but not streaming.

Comment: There questions doesn't ask for a concrete solution but for a software/library recommendation. Please re-post it at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

As the author of `jhdf` thought I would add my answer. I am not aware of any other pure Java libraries attempting to read HDF5. This is the main reason I started writing one. Although `jhdf` currently doesn't support slicing or streaming I would certainly like to add it in the future, but that's probably still a while off. Having said that several gigabyte files should be OK with enough heap space so might still be worth a try. You would probably need an xmx about double the size of the dataset you want to open. I have opened several gigabyte datasets successfully using `jhdf`.

Comment: From my tests I need at least 3 times the size of the dataset into the Xmx (which I have not at all) . An other limitation of jhdf for my scenario is the only possibility to read a file or a bytes array. As I am having a stream and not a file, I am limited by the max array size and would have to wrote the file on the disk before opening it. As I was not able to do any streaming support I wrote a client that convert HDF5 in a custom format (using netcdf-java because it has slicing) that I can easily read in streaming (and compress as well as original hdf5 through the network using gzip).